Is there a free online/cloud proxy for scraping content from Israel?
That is, an online service to which you give a website and it scrapes it from an Israeli IP address and returns the content, and you can utilize this proxy in your online scripts.
It could be limited in credits (e.g. 1,000 free scrapes a month) or maybe even a free trial mode, if that's what it takes.
It's for a free public JSON file that seems to accept just Israeli connections.

You will have a higher chance if you look for VPN providers that have servers in Israel. VPN providers also often have free and trial periods, especially for mobile apps like Android.

But this is about cloud providers for online scripts.
